# Backing Up in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a a package that I will be constantly updating. I will be releasing each update to the android market. But if there is an issue with a specific version I will need to be able to go to that version and check the code.

Is there a way to backup an entire project and save it in such a way that I could view version 1 then version 3 etc without having to revert the current versions files back?

Sorry if this is confusing. I am confused about how I should do this in the first place. So any help would be great.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Version Control Systems for that purpose.  Look [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) for more details.

Comment: @Max is looking for the ability to restore the Eclipse **project**.  I am not familiar with Android tooling for Eclipse.  It will require more than just a VCS -- unless of course you store all your project files in a VCS too!

Comment: I think using VCS means to store the project files to VCS trunk isn't it? If not, whats the use of VCS?

Comment: actually, no, it won't. Eclipse is perfectly able to restore a project from, say an SVN tag if you have to right files commited. Otherwise, that really would be pointless, wouldn't it?

Comment: Clarifying my comment about storing Eclipse **project** files: I was referring to Eclipse _metadata_ like `.project` and `.classpath` and such.  I was **not** talking about project source files.  Simply storing the project source files in name-your-favorite-VCS won't revert your **Eclipse project** state back to an earlier version.

Comment: @Sr Sankaran: what is the problem with storing eclipse files with your project on your VCS ? if you don't, switching from a branch to another is totally a pain in the a**

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to it:

1. Use Source Version Control like VSS, Perforce, CSV, SVN, GIT e.t.c.
2. Use Eclipse Local history to tell you where you were at a given point in time (if you cant move your code to Source Version Control), you can choose how many days and size of backup by selecting  Window - > Preferences - > Workspace - > Local History

Comment: i don;t think second option is reliable one because you wouldn't know exactly which version you want to restore. You have to check each local history with luck to find the stable one.

Comment: well as I mentioned in my answer (if you cant move your code to Source Version Control) then Eclipse Local History is one way (of many to go)